# How to give user input as number in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I have following dockerfile,

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Installing & building WRF
RUN tar -xvzf  WRFV4.0.TAR.gz \
&& cd ./WRF \
&& ./configure -$'34\r1\r'  \
&& ./compile em_real >& log.compile \
&& cd ..
```

when I run "./configure" command in terminal I have to select some options for configuration, as an example select option 1-70 : 34.

How do I do this thing in my Dockerfile, I have tried above method and few other method but no luck.

Comment: have a look at build args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution using this [git repo](https://github.com/rdccosmo/containered-wrf.git).

Using the Dockerfile in above repo I have changed my Dockerfile as follows which is working fine now,

```
RUN tar -xvzf  WRFV4.0.TAR.gz \
&& cd ./WRF \
&& echo 34 | ./configure  \
&& ./compile em_real >& log.compile \
&& cd ..
```